# Send form in JSON using Thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using a form using Thymeleaf to send data to my Service.

Here is my Form:

```
<form th:object="${individualEntity}" th:action="@{/save}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>FirstName:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{individualName.givenName}"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>LastName:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{individualName.surname}"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{address}"/>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

When I debug the request sent using this form it gives me this data : individualName.givenName=xxxx&individualName.surname=xxxxx&address=xxxx

However I want that it will be in JSON when sending because my microservice consumes JSON.

What should I do to correct that !

Here is my service:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "save")
public String saveIndividual(Individual individual){
    individualService.saveIndividual(individual);
    return "redirect:/getIndividual/" + individual.getId();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at annotating with `@ResponseBody`